# Force label to the left in VennDiagram

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am trying to produce a Venn diagram using the R VennDiagram package (v 1.6.20), with function draw.pairwise.venn, where :

I have two categories "Method_1" & "Method_2" (thus draw.pairwise.venn) 
For Method_2, all of its labels are included in Method_1.

My issue is that when drawing the Venn, labels which are specific to Method_1 are displayed on the right part of the Venn, which is confusing because if you don't pay attention to colors, you might think they correspond to Method_2 labels. **[See figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tdCq.jpg)**

*Ps* : Switching categories (putting Method_1 on the right) is not an option because in this study we produce many Venn diagrams and want to always have Method_1 on the left and Method_2 on the right.

Code for figure 1 :

```
M1 <- c("toto", "tata", "titi")
M2 <- "toto"
if (all(M2 %in% M1)) {
    v <- draw.pairwise.venn(
      area1 = 100,
      area2 = 35,
      cross.area = 35,
      category = c("Method_1", "Method_2"),
      fill = c("navajowhite", "lightskyblue1"),
      lty = "blank",
      cex = 1.1,
      cat.cex = 2.1,
      cat.dist = c(0.03, 0.112),
      cat.pos = c(330, 30),
      margin = 0.04,
      cat.col = c("sienna4", "darkblue")
    )

    v[[5]]$label <- paste(intersect(M1, M2), collapse = "\n")
    v[[6]]$label <- paste(setdiff(M1, M2), collapse = "\n")
    grid.newpage()
    grid.draw(v)
}
```

I did try to toy with $hjust & $just for the labels on the right part of the Venn.  
 $hjust is behaving as ~ expect, but this is not the case for $just. **[See figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UENLc.jpg)**

> > str(v[[6]]) 
>  List of 11 
>   $ label        : chr "tata\ntiti"
>   
>   $ x            : 'unit' num 0.828npc 
>    ..- attr(*,
>   "valid.unit")= int 0 
>    ..- attr(*, "unit")= chr "npc" 
>   $ y
>   : 'unit' num 0.5npc 
>    ..- attr(*, "valid.unit")= int 0 
>    ..-
>   attr(*, "unit")= chr "npc" 
>   $ just         : chr "centre" 
>   $
>   hjust        : NULL 
>   $ vjust        : NULL 
>   $ rot          :
>   num 0 
>   $ check.overlap: logi FALSE 
>   $ name         : chr
>   "GRID.text.431" 
>   $ gp           :List of 5 
>    ..$ col       :
>   chr "black" 
>    ..$ cex       : num 1.1 
>    ..$ fontface  : chr
>   "plain" 
>    ..$ fontfamily: chr "serif" 
>    ..$ font      :
>   Named int 1 
>    .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "plain" 
>    ..-
>   attr(*, "class")= chr "gpar" 
>   $ vp           : NULL 
>    - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "text" "grob" "gDesc"

Updates for figure 2 :

```
v[[6]]$hjust <- 17 # Default = NULL
v[[6]]$just <- "left" # Default = "centre"
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(v)
```

How to force "good" left alignment for Method_1 labels ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`just` and `hjust` do basically the same. If I understand correctly, you want to change the position of the label, independently of the justification. You can do that with the `x` variable:

```
M1 <- c("toto", "tata", "titi")
M2 <- "toto"
if (all(M2 %in% M1)) {
    v <- draw.pairwise.venn(
      area1 = 100,
      area2 = 35,
      cross.area = 35,
      category = c("Method_1", "Method_2"),
      fill = c("navajowhite", "lightskyblue1"),
      lty = "blank",
      cex = 1.1,
      cat.cex = 2.1,
      cat.dist = c(0.03, 0.112),
      cat.pos = c(330, 30),
      margin = 0.04,
      cat.col = c("sienna4", "darkblue")
    )

    v[[5]]$label <- paste(intersect(M1, M2), collapse = "\n")
    v[[6]]$label <- paste(setdiff(M1, M2), collapse = "\n")
    v[[6]]$just <- "left"
    v[[6]]$x <- unit(0.15, 'npc')
    grid.newpage()
    grid.draw(v)
}
```

[image: Changing label positions in Venndiagram]

You can change or eliminate the line `v[[6]]$just <- "left"` to achieve the relative distribution you want in `v[[6]]`.